# Disable WooCommerce Address State Dropdown

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

[image]

As you can see, WooCommerce's State fields use select field.

But, I just want user enter State directly!

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your functions.php

Simply add this code to your functions file and your WooCommerce will now use standard drop downs.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'agentwp_dequeue_stylesandscripts', 100 );
function agentwp_dequeue_stylesandscripts() {
if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) ) {
wp_dequeue_style( 'select2' );
wp_deregister_style( 'select2' );
wp_dequeue_script( 'select2');
wp_deregister_script('select2');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#billing_address_1').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?